# LAN connection not working for 100mbps half/full and auto for one particular LAN point

Tags: networking, lan, ethernet, switch

I use unlimited broadband internet connection through LAN provided by our internet provider, without any domestic router. Recently, I am not able to connect my ACER laptop to the net as a message appears in Google Chrome: 'unable to connect to the net', when I set Auto or 100 Mbps half/full in the 'speed and duplex' of properties in LAN connections.

When I called up my service provider, they told me to recheck my IPv4 properties and then change the speed and duplex to 10 Mbps half/full, But this did not solve the problem. They told me to ping at 10 Mbps in CMD but it displayed 'request timed out'.

When we are connecting other laptops at this same LAN point, the connection is coming pretty well. The strange thing is that the LAN in this computer is working properly at both 10 and 100 Mbps at other points and when connecting to other computers. I even disabled Windows Firewall and antivirus programs to avoid blocking of the net. Also I formatted the whole computer twice but the problem persisted. Now both the internet providers and computer dealers are saying they cannot help anymore regarding this matter!

Comment: what kind of switch do you have? can you log into it? did you ping by ip or hostname, and do you have any DNS settings set for that interface? whats your OS?

Comment: Have you tried switching cables?

Comment: my OS is windows xp. The cable cannot be changed as it is provided by our service provider and comes from their office. And the dns settings have been changed and adjusted by the provider.